# Generics in constructors in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm able to do this in Java:

```
public <T extends Bar & Baz> Foo(T arg) { ... }
```

In `Foo`'s constructor, `arg` is typed such that it extends `Bar` and implements `Baz`. This is done without adding a type parameter to `Foo` (i.e. `class Foo<T extends Bar & Baz>`). How do I do the same in Kotlin? something like:

```
constructor<T>(arg: T) where T : Bar, T : Baz { ... }
```

**Update:** I'd like to add more context, I'm using dagger in Android which requires me to do this:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun Foo(): Foo
```

It fails with `@ContributesAndroidInjector methods cannot return parameterized types` when I do this:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun Foo(): Foo<*>
```

This is why adding a type parameter (similar to `ysakhno`'s answer) is not a solution.

Comment: So essentially you need a default constructor (in addition to a constructor with an argument)?

Comment: Just to understand the use-case: how would you use the parameterized argument of the constructor if the class has no type argument?

Comment: `@ContributesAndroidInjector` is typically used for classes listed in the Android manifest, and those classes don't have constructor arguments.  What problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your specific needs. Hope that helps.

Comment: My advice would be to simply make it a factory method instead of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Kotlin, albeit with the primary constructor. Here is an example:

```
interface Baz

open class Bar

class Foo<T>(arg: T) where T : Bar, T : Baz {
    init {
        println(arg)
    }
}

class BarBaz : Bar(), Baz

fun main() {
    val bar = Bar()
    val baz = object : Baz {}
    val bb = BarBaz()

    val fooBarBaz = Foo(bb) // This one works
    val fooBar = Foo(bar) // Although this one does not (bar does not implement Baz)
    val fooBaz = Foo(baz) // This one does not work also (baz does not extend Bar)
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you really need to have a class without a generic type parameter, and yet also have a generic 'constructor' of a sort, I don't think there is other way in Kotlin than resorting to a companion object. Like so:

```
interface Baz

open class Bar

class Foo {

    companion object {
        fun <T> create(arg: T): Foo where T : Bar, T : Baz {
            val inst = Foo() // Note that class Foo is not parameterized
            println(arg)
            // Do something else with the instance here, if needed
            return inst
        }
    }
}

class BarBaz : Bar(), Baz

fun main() {
    val bar = Bar()
    val baz = object : Baz {}
    val bb = BarBaz()

    val fooBarBaz = Foo.create(bb) // This one still works
    // The following two do not work for the same reasons as with parameterized class
    val fooBar = Foo.create(bar)
    val fooBaz = Foo.create(baz)
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know the reason for a down-vote. I believe the answer is on-point, and I am confident the example works, because I tested it before posting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was one of my attempted solutions, please see updated question. (i did not downvote)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
class Foo<T : Any>(arg: T) { // ": Any" forces the type to be non nullable

    // Arg is a "constructor" parameter so you can access it on the init block
    init {
        println(arg::class)
    }
}
```

Any constructor in a Kotlin class must call another one, and lastly it will call the class main constructor (which is the one defined in the  class declaration itself.

You can think on the class declaration as the main constructor declaration. and on the `init` block as the body of the main constructor.